# Create PDF from map document (mxd) without Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcpy, export, pdf

I've been trying to export map data (mxd) and combine into a PDF. I'm successful in creating the two PDFs, but can't combine them.

How do I correct this error?

> finalPDFDoc isn't defined

I'm very new to Python.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.mapping import *

env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = "C:\\ClassData\\Python_4080\\wk_8\\Lesson8_Data"

output_folder = "C:\\ClassData\\Python_4080\\wk_8\\Lesson8_Data\\Results"

#OPEN and work with map documents
mapDoc = MapDocument("C:\\ClassData\\Python_4080\\wk_8\\Lesson8_Data\\Lesson8.mxd")

#TODO define data frame

dataFrames = ListDataFrames(mapDoc)
dataFrame = dataFrames[0]       #gets first data frame to export

#output paths of exported maps. 1st is in data view and 2nd in layout view.
pdfPathdf = "C:/ClassData/Python_4080/wk_8/Lesson8_Data/Results/lesson8df"
pdfPathpl = "C:/ClassData/Python_4080/wk_8/Lesson8_Data/Results/lesson8pl"

#Export map in dataview, with data frame as third parameter
ExportToPDF(mapDoc, pdfPathdf, dataFrame, df_export_width = 1200, df_export_height = 800)

#Export map in layoutview, with constant as third parameter
ExportToPDF(mapDoc, pdfPathpl, "PAGE_LAYOUT", df_export_width = 1200, df_export_height = 800)
print "PDF has been generated at " + pdfPathdf


####### This doesn't run ###############

################################################################################
####################################################################################
#Add components to new PDFs. Merging the two views into one PDF

finalPDFDoc.appendPages(pdfPathdf)  
finalPDFDoc.appendPages(pdfPathpl)
finalPDFDoc.saveACopy("C:\\ClassData\\Python_4080\\wk_8\\Lesson8_Data\\Results\\Final_PDF")

finalPDFDoc.close()
del finalPDFDoc
```

Comment: I think you need to create finalPDFDoc before you can append to it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your `finalPDFDoc` variable before you can append to it or delete it.

```
finalPDFDoc = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(r"C:\ClassData\Python_4080\wk_8\Lesson8_Data\Results\Final_PDF")

finalPDFDoc.appendPages(pdfPathdf)  
finalPDFDoc.appendPages(pdfPathpl)

finalPDFDoc.saveAndClose()
```

For more info and documentation see [ArcGIS Desktop Help - PDFDocument](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/pdfdocument-class.htm)

Comment: I tried this and keep getting 'invalid path'. I can't see it.pdfPathdf = "C:/ClassData/Python_4080/wk_8/lesson8df.pdf"
pdfPathpl = "C:/ClassData/Python_4080/wk_8/lesson8pl.pdf"

finalPDFDoc = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(r"C:\\ClassData\\Python_4080\\wk_8\\Final_PDF.pdf")

finalPDFDoc.appendPages(pdfPathdf)  
finalPDFDoc.appendPages(pdfPathpl)

finalPDFDoc.saveAndClose()

Comment: @Ann Try removing the `r` in front of the path from the `finalPDFDoc = ` line, or changing the double slash to single in that line

Comment: Still getting invalid path in the for the same line finalPDFDoc. I've tried both suggestions. It has to be in the pdfPathdf line, I think.
dataFrames = ListDataFrames(mapDoc)
dataFrame = dataFrames[0]

pdfPathdf = "C:/ClassData/Python_4080/wk_8/Lesson8_Data/lesson8df.pdf"
pdfPathpl = "C:/ClassData/Python_4080/wk_8/Lesson8_Data/lesson8pl.pdf"

finalPDFDoc = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate("C:/ClassData/Python_4080/wk_8/Final_PDF.pdf")

finalPDFDoc.appendPages(pdfPathdf)  
finalPDFDoc.appendPages(pdfPathpl)

finalPDFDoc.saveAndClose()

Comment: @Ann  please edit your question to include this new info

Comment: @Ann what is the full "invalid path" error message?